# Retrieving/referencing information within dataframes contained in dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary, data-retrieval

I have created a dictionary filled with dataframes which have stored data from 11 different simulations. I now need to extract data from each of the frames to perform my analysis.

```
x=np.arange(0,11)

df_stiff={}

for i in x:

    name='df_stiff' + str(i)

    df_stiff[name]=pd.DataFrame()
```

However whenever I have tried to retrieve/extract information from the dateframes, I have been unable to do so.

I have tried using the syntax **df_stiff[df_stiff0]** etc... however, I keep getting an error that **df_stiff0** is undefined (despite it being the key value and title of of one of the data frames in the dictionary). Can anyone help me with the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing the quote marks - use `df_stiff['df_stiff0']`. As it is now you're trying to index using a variable `df_stiff0` which is indeed undefined.